# AWS S3 sync command gets different results on the same machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to sync data from S3 to local file.

I create 2 connection sessions to the target host. However, using the same sync command, one session sync data `NORMALLY` while the other one, I get

```
fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

Why could this happen and how to avoid this issue?

BTW, they were not run at the same time.

The command is:

```
/usr/local/bin/aws s3 sync s3://${my_s3_path}/ ${my_local_path} --exclude '*xxx' --page-size 400
```

Comment: Any other error message? Looks like you're missing proper IAM credentials

Comment: Hi @Pelocho Thanks for your reply. This is the only error message shown in the console. In my view...these commands are actually run on the same machine using same `~/.aws/credential` file, if proper credential is missing, both of them should fail...

Comment: Then the only thing that comes to my mind is to check that there are no environment variables messing up with the credentials (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) and that the `$my_s3_path` is properly interpolated. Maybe in the second execution you're trying to sync from an S3 bucket you don't have permissions?